# Aligning elements horizontally and vertically

Tags: tables, pgfplots, graphics, floats

I'm trying to align 3 elements into two columns, the second one having two elements stacked vertically. Here's a picture illustrating what I mean:
[image]

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

$l = 185m$; \\
$S = 5 \cdot 10^{-9}m^2$;\\
$\lambda = 4,24 \cdot 10^{-3} K^{-1}$;

\begin{tabular} { | c | c |}
\hline
    $t_i$ & $R_i$ \\ \hline
    23,4 & $0,620 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    25,4 & $0,623 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    27,4 & $0,626 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    29,4 & $0,631 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    31,4 & $0,635 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    33,4 & $0,640 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    35,4 & $0,644 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    37,4 & $0,649 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    29,4 & $0,653 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    41,4 & $0,658 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    43,4 & $0,663 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    45,4 & $0,667 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    47,4 & $0,672 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    49,4 & $0,677 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    51,4 & $0,682 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    53,4 & $0,687 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    55,4 & $0,692 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
    57,4 & $0,696 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
59,4 & $0,701 \cdot 10^3$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={$R = f(t)$},
xlabel={Temperatūra (\textdegree C)},
ylabel={Varža ($\Omega)$},
ymax=700,
xmin=23.4,
ymajorgrids=true,   
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
 ]
 coordinates {
    (23.4, 620)(25.4, 623)(27.4, 626)(29.4, 631)(31.4, 635)(33.4, 640)(35.4, 644)(37.4, 649)(39.4, 653)(41.4, 658)(43.4, 663)(45.4, 667)(47.4, 672)(49.4, 677)(51.4, 682)(53.4, 687)(55.4, 692)(57.4, 696)(59.4, 701)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm afraid I don't even see where are the two elements which have to be stacked? The graph and the sort of legend above it? And what are you trying to obtain?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use and which LaTeX packages you employ.

Comment: But what are you trying to obtain? The graph and the legend have to be vertically centred w.r.t. the table on the left side, and have to be vertically centred  w.r.t. each other?

Comment: Right now, the table blocks (don't know what's the correct terminology here) all of the space to it's right. I'd like to make better use of that space by having the graph and the legend there. I don't really care what the alignment is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of packages loaded in MWE preamble I redesign of your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}% only for show page layout
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                                    >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X
                                 @{} }
\begin{tabular}   {S[table-format=2.1]
                   S[table-format=1.3,
                     table-figures-exponent=1]}
    \toprule
{$t_i$} &   {$R_i$} \\
    \midrule
23,4    &   0,620e3 \\
25,4    &   0,623e3 \\
27,4    &   0,626e3 \\
29,4    &   0,631e3 \\
31,4    &   0,635e3 \\  \addlinespace
33,4    &   0,640e3 \\
35,4    &   0,644e3 \\
37,4    &   0,649e3 \\
29,4    &   0,653e3 \\
41,4    &   0,658e3 \\  \addlinespace
43,4    &   0,663e3 \\
45,4    &   0,667e3 \\
47,4    &   0,672e3 \\
49,4    &   0,677e3 \\
51,4    &   0,682e3 \\  \addlinespace
53,4    &   0,687e3 \\
55,4    &   0,692e3 \\
57,4    &   0,696e3 \\
59,4    &   0,701e3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    &
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \addlinespace   % emulate vertical space of toprule in the table on the left
$l =  \SI{185}{m}$;             \\
$S =  \SI{5e-9}{\square\metre}$;\\
$\lambda = \SI{4,24e-3}{\per\kelvin}$;\\
    \addlinespace[2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={$R = f(t)$},
xlabel={Temperatūra (\si{\degreeCelsius})},
ylabel={Varža (\si{\ohm})},
ymax=700,
xmin=23.4,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
            ]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=square]
 coordinates {
    (23.4, 620)(25.4, 623)(27.4, 626)(29.4, 631)(31.4, 635)(33.4, 640)(35.4, 644)(37.4, 649)(39.4, 653)(41.4, 658)(43.4, 663)(45.4, 667)(47.4, 672)(49.4, 677)(51.4, 682)(53.4, 687)(55.4, 692)(57.4, 696)(59.4, 701)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{My figure with table \dots}
\label{fig:important figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! And thanks for the extra changes, I'm very new to this so I tend to do things the other way around.

Comment: @PoVa, see edited answer ... in the first version I  upload one before last version of code and image (where  were some spurious lines which help me to see alignment of figure elements)  and correct decimal mark from dot to comma. Happy TeX-ing!